# WooCommerce reload price on single product page

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm building a WooCommerce webshop where the (variable) products have graduated discounts based on their quantity. For example; from 0 till 10 items the price is €20, from 11 items till 20 items the price is €19, etc...

To set the discounts for each product variation, I have used a filter hook, which works fine once the page reloads.

I want to know if there is a way to reload my product price via ajax once I change the product quantity on the single product page? Because from the moment I set the quantity to 11 items, I want my price on the frontend to change to €19.

Basically, I want to revoke my price filter via ajax.

My code to manipulate the product variation prices:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'ga_change_product_price', 10, 2);

function ga_change_product_price($price, $product)
{
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $current_user_customer_group = get_user_meta($current_user_id, 'customer_group')[0];
    $current_variation_id = $product->get_id();
    $parent_id = $product->get_parent_id();
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    // Iterate over the custom price rows
    if (have_rows('custom_prices', $parent_id)) :

        while (have_rows('custom_prices', $parent_id)) : the_row();

            $variation_id = get_sub_field('variation_id');
            $customer_id = get_sub_field('customer_id');
            $customer_group = get_sub_field('customer_group');
            $min_qty = get_sub_field('min_qty');
            $max_qty = get_sub_field('max_qty');

            // If customer discount && graduated discount
            if ($variation_id == $current_variation_id && $customer_id == $current_user_id && !empty($min_qty) && !empty($max_qty)) {

                $cart_qty = 0;

                // Check the number of items in the cart of this specific variation id
                foreach ($cart as $cart_item) {
                    $cart_item_variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];

                    if ($cart_item_variation_id == $variation_id) {
                        $cart_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];
                    }
                }

                if ($cart_qty >= $min_qty && $cart_qty <= $max_qty) {
                    $price = get_sub_field('price');
                }
            }

            // If customer discount && no graduated discount
            else if ($variation_id == $current_variation_id && $customer_id == $current_user_id) {
                $price = get_sub_field('price');
            }

            // If group discount && graduated discount
            else if ($variation_id == $current_variation_id && $customer_group == $current_user_customer_group && !empty($min_qty) && !empty($max_qty)) {

                $cart_qty = 0;

                // Check the number of items in the cart of this specific variation id
                foreach ($cart as $cart_item) {
                    $cart_item_variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];

                    if ($cart_item_variation_id == $variation_id) {
                        $cart_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];
                    }
                }

                if ($cart_qty >= $min_qty && $cart_qty <= $max_qty) {
                    $price = get_sub_field('price');
                }
            }

            // If group discount && no graduated discount
            else if ($variation_id == $current_variation_id && $customer_group == $current_user_customer_group) {
                $price = get_sub_field('price');
            }

        endwhile;

    endif;

    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Pieter.
When you update quantity inside of the cart page, you have to use the update cart button, where you could add your function to make this work without the need of Ajax.

Comment: Hi @PeriklisKakarakidis, thanks for your reply. I know how it works on the cart page, but I would like to see it happen as well on my single product page before I add the product to the cart.

Comment: Would you be intrested in a Jquery type of solution? Where the ammout of items selected via the single page quantity buttons are the events being triggered and the javascript reads and runs functions based on the number displayed in the quantity box.

Comment: @PeriklisKakarakidis, yes, in the meantime I handled it via jQuery and an Ajax request.